# How to integrate google maps API in angular js project on web storm

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Can someone please guide me through the process of including and integrating javascript google maps api in angularjs project on webstorm. Generally I have done this by using simple html file, but when I try to include the same google maps api and code in an angularjs project, the view of maps is not rendered. Thanks, I'll be really greatefull for the help.

Answer (score 0):

this is an  [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/k5c2ndyL/)  how to integrate google maps in your angularjs project

javascript:

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('myMap', function() {
    // directive link function
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var map, infoWindow;
        var markers = [];

        // map config
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 2),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        };

        // init the map
        function initMap() {
            if (map === void 0) {
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
            }
        }    

        // place a marker
        function setMarker(map, position, title, content) {
            var marker;
            var markerOptions = {
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: title,
                icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
            };

            marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
            markers.push(marker); // add marker to array

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                // close window if not undefined
                if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                    infoWindow.close();
                }
                // create new window
                var infoWindowOptions = {
                    content: content
                };
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        // show the map and place some markers
        initMap();

        setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(51.508515, -0.125487), 'London', 'Just some content');
        setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(52.370216, 4.895168), 'Amsterdam', 'More content');
        setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614, 2.352222), 'Paris', 'Text here');
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };
});
```

html:

```
<div my-map=""></div>
```

css:

```
#gmaps {
width: 450px;
height: 450px;
}
```

Comment: try this answer and give me a feedback

Comment: I have simply included the given files, there are no errors according to anything hence the page upon which <div my-map=""> is rendering but still the map is not being rendered.

Comment: How would I call the setMarker method from a controller?

Comment: @FaizanAhmed if the answer is correct and useful, please up vote and tick the answer